# How to log custom Pytorch model with Mlflow?

Tags: pytorch, mlflow

I have been using Presumm https://github.com/nlpyang/PreSumm for text summarization.

However, in `src/train_abstractive.py`, the model learner `trainer` is not a `torch.nn.Module`. However, the input `AbsSummarizer` is an extension of the `torch.nn.Module` class.

I want to use `mlflow.pytorch.log_model` to save the model as a native pytorch model. But `trainer` is not a `torch.nn.Module`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

After trainer runs, you should log the `AbsSummarizer`, which should be populated with the updated weights that correspond to the trained model.